# How to specify what owner/group a programatically created folder belongs to

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, drupal

A little background first: I'm doing some Drupal site-building on a Windows 7 machine.  Drupal has an image module which, in short, allows for image caching.  When you create an image style, the module creates a directory. For instance, if you create a style `my_image_style` it will automatically create a folder `sites/default/files/img/styles/my_image_style/and/some/other/folders/beneath`.  However, the created directory has the owner:group `Administrators:System` with permission `d--------+`.  Everything else, going all the way up to root is `chrisrockwell:None`.  Apache (this is a WAMP5 setup) is also `chrisrockwell:None`.

The Drupal module needs to create files in this directory, but cannot because of the permissions issue.

So, in this set-up, how to I specify what user:group a created directory belongs to?

I'm not sure if it has an effect, but I do mostly everything within cygwin (moving around, opening, vim).

Please let me know if you need additional information, or if this is better suited in another site.

UPDATE: If I chmod 777 the entire site directory, the only folder I get permission denied on is the image_style folder that is created by Drupal's script.

Comment: Note, `d---------+` does not mean that there are no permissions; the `+` means that there is an access list associated with the directory that cannot be displayed as simple permissions.

Comment: @DarthAndroid I'm thinking it does have to do with Windows ACL's. Even if I chmod -R 777 the entire directory, running as Administrator, the permissions are still -rw-r--r--. I don't know much about ACL's, so I'm having troubleshooting issues

Comment: I went so far as to give every user, every group, Full Control over this particular directory, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cygwin remarks

This is a workaround rather than an answer.

I've recently run into similar issues with Cygwin. The cause seems to be a misconfiguration in how windows users and groups are mapped to cygwin users and groups. Specifically, I've seen that the "Security" tab in the "file properties" dialog contains "Group or Username" entries such as OWNER and GROUP. I assume these are unsupported by windows.

It may be worth looking into the `mkpasswd` utility and reading up on windows ACLs to resolve this permanently. However, so far I've been able to get rid of all file permission errors by resetting the windows ACLs to defaults like so:

```
wraptor: ~/tmp/su/find-xargs
$ icacls.exe . /reset /t
processed file: .
processed file: .\.search-dirs
processed file: .\.test
processed file: .\dirz
processed file: .\foo
processed file: .\moo
processed file: .\sensors
processed file: .\.test\test.java
processed file: .\dirz\3.java
processed file: .\foo\2.java
processed file: .\moo\1.java
processed file: .\sensors\light.java
Successfully processed 12 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

After this, it's sometimes necessary to traverse the hierarchy and reset the permission bits:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

After these steps, the files are correctly "owned" by windows-me or the Administrator user and native windows programs can read and write these files as usual.

---

### Attempt at an answer

Apart from that, *umask* should be mentioned. It is set in a users' environment (or for a pocess in a program) and governs the permissions of subsequently created files and folders.

e.g (bash)

```
umask 0022
```

This will cause all files and folders to be created with 644 and 755 permissions.

e.g (python)

```
$ cat moo.py
import os
for _ in ('0022', '0002', '0077'):
        os.umask(int(_, 8))
        with open('moo.f-%s' % _, 'w') as f:
                f.writelines("moo\nfoo")

$ python moo.py; ll moo.f-*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1K 2013-07-24 07:46 moo.f-0002
-rw-r--r-- 1 1K 2013-07-24 07:46 moo.f-0022
-rw------- 1 1K 2013-07-24 07:46 moo.f-0077
```

PHP has an "identical" [umask](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) function.

More info here: `man 3p umask`

Comment: I'll look into umask - thanks.  Your work around has solved my current issue and allows me to get back to work on this module.  I'll note that I had to run the .exe from cmd rather than cygwin in order for it to effect.  Thanks much!

Comment: Don't mention it :) If you figure our what's causing Cygwin to clobber windows permissions, I'd appreciate a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar issues with other applications in Windows setting the group wrong when running as Administrator. I don't know how to fix the original directory creation issue, but you can reassign the owner and group for all the directories in cygwin using `chown`:

```
chown -R chrisrockwell:none my_image_style
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already chown'd the directory.  Even though chrisrockwell:None is now the owner:group, the Drupal module still can not read/write.